# Mongoose text search returns empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, search, mongoose

I've been through all the other SO questions, all the docs and can't figure out what the hell I'm doing wrong here.  I just need to get the text search working and then I will flesh out how the api will actually work.

**products.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Id: String,
  title: String,
  description: String
});

ProductSchema.index({'$**': 'text'});

mongoose.model('Products', ProductSchema);
```

**server.js**

```
router.get('/api/feed/red', function(req, res, next) {
   Product.find({$text: {$search: 'red'}})
       .exec(function(err, docs) {
         if (err) return next(err);
         res.json(docs);
       });
});
```

Going to `localhost:8080/api/feed/red` returns an empty array.  I've tested with `Product.find({_id: '587...})` and it works.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the document you're expecting to find with the query?

Comment: Could you check the collection with a editor or the shell to check if the index is set correctly? Do you get the result when executing the query with your editor / shell ? It all looks ok.

Comment: @JohnnyHK - My ProductSchema actually has a bunch more fields, and this specific query should return an array of about 50 documents.

Comment: @HoefMeistert - I haven't run any terminal queries, but I have set up a path to `/products`, which returns all the documents (about 3400 of them)

Comment: @BigBadBigBad Yes i understand, but you need to check if the index is correct in mongo and a simple find({$test : { $search : 'red'}}) returns the required data. When it's working in Mongo (editor of shell) you know it's in mongoose...